# Quotients of polynomial rings and evaluations of the variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

We all know that $\mathbb Z \cong \mathbb Z[X]/(X)$ $(n\mapsto n+(X))$. So intuitively, I was wondering: what if we take a ring $R$ (unitary and commutative if you want) and we consider $R[X]/(X-\alpha)$ where $\alpha \in R$. Does we have $R[\alpha]\cong R[X]/(X-\alpha)$? The idea in a certain sense, is to evaluate $X$ in $\alpha$.

What if we quotient by a polynomial of degree $n$?

Comment: Try with $\alpha = X^2$. What is $R[X]/(X-X^2)$?

Answer (score 0):

You're on to something, but $R[X]/(X-\alpha)$ doesn't make sense if $\alpha\notin R[X]$. However, if $R\subseteq S$ and $\alpha\in S\setminus R$ then we do have $S[X]/(X-\alpha)\cong S$, while the image of $R[X]\subseteq S[X]$ in that quotient map is $R[\alpha]$.

Comment: So we're talking about $\alpha\in R[X]\setminus R$? In that case I misunderstood. However, I hope you see that my answer still addresses one interpretation of "$\alpha \notin R$".

Comment: @Richard There isn't one single trick in evaluating quotient rings in general. It's mostly a lot of experience and practice.

Comment: @Richard Don't delete it. Too many people have put in effort in answers and comments. Write a new and better question, with a link to this one explaining what went wrong.

Comment: But my question has not been understood, so it makes no sense not to delete it. I hope you see the point.